# Files from Windows with 'unsupported reparse point' on ubuntu

Tags: ntfs-3g

I'm trying to pass some files that I have on Windows to a HD. As I lost my Windows user password I'm recovering those files through an Ubuntu usb (20.04 focal). However, some files and folders were shared with OneDrive.
When I copied those files to a HD through Ubuntu they appear as broken symlink and by doing `ls -l` it appears 'unsupported reparse point'. By searching through the Internet I reached the https://jp-andre.pagesperso-orange.fr/advanced-ntfs-3g.html#download page. However, I'm not Linux savy so I don't know what to do.
I have tried doing the given steps:

> Then, you have to download systcomp.zip from
> http://jp-andre.pagesperso-orange.fr/advanced-ntfs-3g.html#download
> and extract the (binary) plugin which matches the cpu you are using.
> For instance, for an x86_64 cpu:
>
> ```
> unzip -x systcomp.zip systcomp/linux-64/ntfs-plugin-80000017.so Now, (as root), you have to relocate the file
> ```
>
> `ntfs-plugin-80000017.so` to the proper ntfs plugin directory. A
> simple way to find this directory, is to run the command:
>
> ```
> strings $(which ntfs-3g) | grep ntfs-plugin
> ```
>
> This will return something like
> `/usr/lib64/ntfs-3g/ntfs-plugin-%08lx.so` which is the pattern to
> locate the plugin (in this case, the plugin must be renamed as
> `/usr/lib64/ntfs-3g/ntfs-plugin-80000017.so`). Your actual plugin
> directory may be different, and you may have to create the directory.

By doing `strings $(which ntfs-3g) | grep ntfs-plugin` I got `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ntfs-3g/ntfs-plugin-%08lx.so`. I created the directory `ntfs-3g` at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` and copied `ntfs-plugin-80000017.so` to this directory. What should I do from this point to get/recover the files that appear 'unsupported reparse point'?

EDIT: I have found more instructions regarding OneDrive

1. download and compile ntfs-3g-2017.3.23AR.1 from
   http://jp-andre.pagesperso-orange.fr/advanced-ntfs-3g.html#download:

   ```
   tar -xf ntfs-3g_ntfsprogs-2017.3.23AR.1.tgz
   cd ntfs-3g_ntfsprogs-2017.3.23AR.1
   ./configure
   make
   ```

   (do not install, so you will not pollute your current installation)
2. download a test version of plugin for OneDrive:

   ```
   wget http://jp-andre.pagesperso-orange.fr/onedrive.zip
   ```

   Extract the plugin matching your CPU, for instance :

   ```
   unzip -x onedrive.zip onedrive/linux-64/ntfs-plugin-9000301a.so
   ```

   Relocate the plugin to /usr/local/lib/ntfs-3g (you may have to create this directory)

   ```
   sudo mv onedrive/linux-64/ntfs-plugin-9000301a.so /usr/local/lib/ntfs-3g
   ```
3. Unmount your Windows directory, and remount it read-only with ntfs-3g_ntfsprogs-2017.3.23AR.1 (from the directory used in step 1):

   ```
   sudo ntfs-3g_ntfsprogs-2017.3.23AR.1/src/ntfs-3g -o ro /dev/your-windows-partition your-windows-mountpoint
   ```
4. List your OneDrive directory and try to access its contents (you may have to do it as root), and report. When done, unmount and remount the usual way.

I have downloaded the `ntfs-3g_ntfsprogs-2017.3.23AR.6.tgz` file and onedrive plugin. However, by executing `sudo ntfs-3g_ntfsprogs-2017.3.23AR.6/src/ntfs-3g -o ro /dev/sda3 /media/ubuntu` it transformed the directory OneDrive/Documents into a broken link that cannot be used as target 'unsupported reparse point 0x9000601a' doesn't exist. How can I solve this?

EDIT 2: I downloaded other onedrive tar, with other plugin. But the problem remained. Apparently the broken files are in the cloud, so

> there is no much hope you could access them through ntfs-3g (Jean-Pierre (jean-pierre-andre) wrote on 2017-12-22:).

I was sure my files were at my local. Is there a way to recover my files? Without knowing my password?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I'm late for the party, but for future readers: I had a very similar issue and it turns out that **OneDrive's feature "files on demand"** caused the folder to be unreadable from Linux.

For the OP: did you try resetting Windows password from live Ubuntu USB? There are many tutorials on how to do so. [Example](https://commons.lbl.gov/display/itfaq/Reset+Windows+Password+using+chntpw+and+Ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

**Disclosure:** I am the developer of the OneDrive Client for Linux - https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive

OneDrive's 'files on-demand' feature cannot be used on Linux by trying to mount the Windows partition and reading your data.

There are only 2 ways for you to use OneDrive on Linux in this manner:

1. Disable in Windows the 'files on-demand' functionality, read https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/advanced-usage.md#configuring-the-client-for-use-in-dual-boot-windows--linux-situations on how to do this, then use the OneDrive Client for Linux to sync your data - https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive
2. Use 'onedriver' (https://github.com/jstaf/onedriver) which is a native file system for OneDrive that supports 'files on-demand'

These are your only two options that are viable and work.

Do not try and 'mount' your Windows partition in Linux to read your OneDrive data if you have 'files on-demand' enabled.